# How do you process collisions in DragonRuby Game Toolkit?

Tags: dragonruby-game-toolkit

I'm using DragonRuby Game Toolkit to build a game.

How do I detect if one object such as a `Sprite` is colliding with another `Sprite`?

Here are two sprites placed on the screen. With a todo of how to check collision:

```rb
def tick args
  # create a sprite
  args.state.sprite_one = { x: 100,
                            y: 200,
                            w: 50,
                            h: 50 } 
    
  # create another sprite that definitely collides
  args.state.sprite_two = { x: 101, 
                            y: 201, 
                            w:  1,
                            h:  1 }
  
  sprites_collide = ????? # help
  
  if sprites_collide
    args.gtk.notify! "sprites collide!"
  else
    args.gtk.notify! "sprites do not collide!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `intersect_rect?` method. This method is available on `Array`, `Hash`, and any class that uses the `attr_sprite` class method.  The source for `intersect_rect?` is [here](https://github.com/DragonRuby/dragonruby-game-toolkit-contrib/blob/master/dragon/geometry.rb#L235).

For this specific example you would do:

```rb
sprites_collide = args.state.sprite_one.intersect_rect? args.state.sprite_two
```